# Is Microsoft SQL the same as Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

And I am having a hard time choosing between MySQL and Microsoft SQL (MSSQL) for my DBMS. I am developing an application in C# which has a desktop and mobile versions with the help of Xamarin. This application is for inventory management system which will deal with many customers, products, orders, etc.

Thank You.

Comment: FWIW, you generally can't run MySQL or MSSQL on a mobile device. Most iOS and Android application use Sqlite for in-app databases.

Answer (score 5):

Your title says "Microsoft SQL" but your question has "MySQL". "My" is not shorthand for "Microsoft" despite sharing the same initial syllable, and no, they are not the same.

- "Microsoft SQL" is not a product, service or nor language. In an appropriate context this term can be shorthand for "Microsoft SQL Server" but I would avoid using this abbreviation because Microsoft has made many products that use some form of SQL (e.g. Access, JET, WMI, SQL Server, etc).
- "MySQL" is an open-source database product originally by MySQL AB in Sweden, now owned by Oracle. It is entirely unrelated to Microsoft SQL Server except that it is also a client/server database product with its own dialect of the SQL query language which has many differences from the T-SQL dialect that Microsoft SQL Server uses.
- "Microsoft SQL Server" is a client/server RDBMS product originally by Sybase and now provided by Microsoft. Its dialect of SQL is called "Transact-SQL" most often referred to as "T-SQL".

Comment: I think "Microsoft SQL" is a reasonable shorthand for Microsoft's implementation of "T-SQL".